# Cannot get borders to display properly in android GridView

Tags: android, android-studio

Despite extensive research here, I cannot find a way to get uniform grid lines in an Android GridView. In my case, every cell in the GridView contains a single TextView object.

Two methods I have found suggested are 1) set the GridView's background to one colour, have a small margin and set all the TextViews' borders to a different colour or 2) create a rectangular border drawable resource and make this the background for the TextViews.

Both these methods hit the same problem. If one TextView is narrower than others in the same column then with method 1, I get huge borders filling all available space in the cell. With option 2, I get a tiny little border that only just encloses the text.

I presume I need a way to ensure each TextView fills the entire column width (or enclose it in a container that does). Any suggestions?

I must say that I'm amazed how hard it is to draw a simple grid with border lines. I've been experimenting for half a day without success. Clearly, I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer. If I set both layout_gravity = "fill_horizontal" and gravity = "center", I get almost what I want. Only almost because the final problem is that now the lines between the cells are twice the weight of the outside border around the whole thing. I presume this is because I am (for example) getting both the right border of one cell and the left border of the adjacent one. I can think of some ways around that but, for now, it will have to do. I am still gobsmacked that such a simple, and presumably common requirement, is so difficult to achieve.